# Multiplying values from 2 different tables

Tags: php, sql

I'm very new at PHP and SQL, so I'm banging my head against the wall about how to get this to achieve the results I'm looking for. I'm working on a product inventory site. The site allows you to enter in an order/quantity received and it updates the total on hand for a specific product.

There is a table for "transactions"; such as receiving more products and a table for "products."

I am trying to multiply the quantity on hand of a product by the unit price for that product so that it will display the total amount invested in that line of product.

Here is the code I'm using - Transactions table is site_trans and Products table is site_products:

```
<form>

<title>Products List</title>
<border>true</border>
<width>580</width>

<fields>
    <_count header="No" suffix="." width="25" align="center" />
    <product_name align="left" header="Name" />
    <product_number align="center" header="Number" />
    <product_count align="center" type="sql" header="Count">
        <sql>
            <vars>
                <table import="$this->tables[transactions]" type="eval" />
                <product import="product_id" type="field" />
            </vars>

            <query>SELECT sum(trans_inventory) FROM {TABLE} WHERE trans_product='{PRODUCT}'</query>
            <field>sum(trans_inventory)</field>
        </sql>

    </product_count>
    <product_cost align="center" header="Cost" />
    <product_uom align="center" header="Unit" />
    <product_totcost align="center" type="sql" header="Total">
        <sql>   
            <vars>
                <table import="$this->tables[transactions]" type="eval" />
                <prodcost import="product_cost" type="field" />
            </vars>
            <query>SELECT sum(trans_inventory), sum('{PRODCOST}') FROM site_trans, site_products WHERE trans_product=product_id</query>
            <field>sum(trans_inventory*product_cost)</field>
        </sql>
    </product_totcost>

</fields>

<header>
    <titles>true</titles>

    <buttons>
        <export onclick="" button="export">
            <location>index.php?sub=export&action=products</location>
        </export>

        <add button="addnew">               
            <location>index.php?sub=products&action=add&returnurl={CURRENT_PAGE}</location>
        </add>
    </buttons>
</header>

<buttons>

    <delete onclick="" button="delete" >
        <location>javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record ?')) window.location='index.php?sub=products&action=delete&product_id={PRODUCT_ID}&returnURL={CURRENT_PAGE}'</location>
    </delete>

    <details onclick="" button="details" >
        <location>index.php?sub=products&action=details&section=1&product_id={PRODUCT_ID}&returnurl={CURRENT_PAGE}</location>
    </details>

</buttons>

<items>25</items>
```

The specific portion of code that is giving me the problem is this:

```
        <product_totcost align="center" type="sql" header="Total">
        <sql>   
            <vars>
                <table import="$this->tables[transactions]" type="eval" />
                <prodcost import="product_cost" type="field" />
            </vars>
            <query>SELECT sum(trans_inventory), sum('{PRODCOST}') FROM site_trans, site_products WHERE trans_product=product_id</query>
            <field>sum(trans_inventory*product_cost)</field>
        </sql>
    </product_totcost>
```

**PLEASE HELP! :)**

To add to this; here is the code for the transactions (add.xml) that updates the quantity on hand for each product in the site_trans database. Maybe this code will shed some light on what we're missing (I don't know)

```
<form>
<title>{PRIVATE.FORM_ACTION_TITLE} Transaction</title>
<action>index.php?sub=transactions&action=store</action>
<name>edit</name>
<width>580</width>

<formtag>true</formtag>
<border>true</border>

<buttons>       
    <set>
        <footer>true</footer>
        <header>true</header>
    </set>

    <return onclick="" button="return">
        <location>{PRIVATE.FORM_PREVIOUS_PAGE}</location>
    </return>

    <save onclick="" button="saveall">
        <location>javascript:document.forms[0].submit();</location>
    </save>

</buttons>

<redirect>index.php?sub=accounts</redirect>

<fields>
    <trans_id type="hidden" hidden="true"/>
    <trans_date type="hidden" default="time()" action="eval"/>
    <trans_user type="hidden" default="$_SESSION[minibase][raw][user_id]" action="eval"/>
    <trans_post_ip type="hidden" default="$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]" action="eval"/>
    <trans_relation type="hidden" default="$_GET[trans_relation]" action="eval"/>
    <trans_product type="hidden" default="$_GET[trans_relation]" action="eval"/>

    <trans_inventory type="textbox" size="5" required="true" validate="A:2:200">            
        <title>Inventory</title>            
        <description>Box to either add (+40) or remove inventory (-40).</description>
    </trans_inventory>

    <trans_date2 type="date" now="true">
        <title>Date</title>

        <fields>
            <month format="int" default="now" />
            <day format="int" default="now" />
            <year from="2011" to="2110" default="now"/>
        </fields>
    </trans_date2>


    <trans_description type="textarea" size="60:4">         
        <title>Description</title>          
    </trans_description>

</fields>
```

Comment: Wbat language/templating language is this? :S

Comment: php I think. Most of the code was free and I've attempted to modify it to work for what I need it to do. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I know how to answer your question as I'm very new to SQL and PHP. Is there something in the coding that will tell me what it is you're asking? Or did I answer it? lol

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry. This is part of an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what framework do you use, but maybe something like this...

```
<query>SELECT sum(trans_inventory*product_cost), sum('{PRODCOST}') FROM site_trans, site_products WHERE trans_product=product_id</query>
<field>sum(trans_inventory*product_cost)</field>
```

It's only a guess.

EDIT:

```
<query>SELECT sum(st.trans_inventory*sp.product_cost) as total, sum('{PRODCOST}') FROM site_trans as st, site_products as sp WHERE st.trans_product=sp.product_id</query>
<field>total</field>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the error that your code gives me:

SELECT sum(trans_inventory*product_cost), sum('$3.59') FROM site_trans, site_products WHERE trans_product=product_idColumn 'product_cost' in field list is ambiguous

Forgive me for the dumb question, but what exactly do mean by framework? It's in MySQL through PHPAdmin. I'm not sure I know how to answer that.

Comment: Yeah I tought that this is an xml file, but I'm not sure what will it modify. Did you try what @mohsensajjadi said?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it and it's doing something, but not quite there yet. It displays "0" in the "Total" column. It should be the sum of 200*3.59

Answer (score 0):

While you have not mentioned what the error was in your original question and the problematic code:

```
        <product_totcost align="center" type="sql" header="Total">
        <sql>   
            <vars>
                <table import="$this->tables[transactions]" type="eval" />
                <prodcost import="product_cost" type="field" />
            </vars>
            <query>SELECT sum(trans_inventory), sum('{PRODCOST}') FROM site_trans, site_products WHERE trans_product=product_id</query>
            <field>sum(trans_inventory*product_cost)</field>
        </sql>
    </product_totcost>
```

from you answer to the previous response it seems you need to qualify your field names, so a possible solution might be:

```
<query>SELECT sum(st.trans_inventory*sp.product_cost), sum('{PRODCOST}') FROM site_trans st, site_products sp WHERE st.trans_product=sp.product_id</query>
<field>sum(st.trans_inventory*sp.product_cost)</field>
```

Comment: Initially, I didn't get an error. The "Total" field was just blank. When I attempted the code from the first answer I received the message "SELECT sum(trans_inventory*product_cost), sum('$3.59') FROM site_trans, site_products WHERE trans_product=product_idColumn 'product_cost' in field list is ambiguous" I will try your fix and see if that does it. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. Well, that code did something, but it's still not giving the correct result. Now the "Total" column displays "0" which is not the correct sum of 200*3.59